# Implement licensing in SpFx?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, licensing

I have created 4 web parts using SPFX. Now I want implement licensing.

If the user has purchase license then can access web part else user is redirected to license.

- What is the best approach to fulfilling this requirement?
- Should I create license component in each web part?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I won't recommend you to keep your license on the client side. Since the SPFx is completely client side module, anyone can easily go through the code and find all the details, how you are using licensing in you web part.

To your problem, I can recommend using `Azure Functions`. They are very powerful when it's come to `serverless computing` (as quoted my Microsoft).

Follow the URL to know more about them. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/

Comment: no we don't wanna go for azure..

Comment: then you can go with WCF approach, write your own web service, host them in your environment and use it in SPFx web part. Its not good to write license module in client side.

Comment: yeh i know that..My question is how can i implement it on client side.I mean can i create license component in each webpart or any other way i can use it?

Comment: In case you have four different SPFx solutions, than Create one more Node.js solution for licensing only. Put all the code related to licensing in it. Export this module and include it in your other SPFx solutions. In case you have all the 4 web part within same solution, than simply add licensing module within the SPFx solution only and use it in all of the web parts.

Comment: I would highly suggest that you make sure that the licensing check makes an off-box call that you make it async and after the webpart has completed rendering.  If it fails, then update the div with your error / link / etc.  Don't block the normal experience flow though.

Comment: @ThinkB4Code thanks for your answer...yes have all webparts in one solution.Can you provide any link or reference for that? or can i provisioning a page using spfx? is this possible in spfx? i have tried but i didn't get any clue on that

Comment: I am not sure about page provisioning in SPFx, but why you require that? Your licensing should be a different project. It could be a web project or it could be a WCF project which you can host on your own servers,  or an Azure Functions. The only thing should be available in your SPFx is service calls (or license module) using HTTP get/post methods to verify if the users hold a valid license or not. It'll better if you implement encryption of data before making calls.

Comment: @ThinkB4Code we are planning to implement license as a webpart project. So that if user have not apply license then user can apply it from webpart.other than that services are ready to call license api.